# Ubunutu software-centre is not working, showing black screen

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, apt

I am trying to open ubuntu software-center but it get paused and after that shows complete black and nothing is happening.

Same thing has happened when I try to run from command line. This is the response from it.

```
$ software-center
2013-10-22 18:41:33,104 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-10-22 18:41:33,108 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-10-22 18:41:33,548 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-10-22 18:41:33,702 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
```

as for a  solutions I tried:

1. trying to remove it

   ```
   $sudo apt-get purge software-center
   $sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. once again install it

   ```
   $sudo apt-get install software-center
   ```

but again same thing is happening.

Can anybody suggest me something onto this?

Comment: Have you tried `aptitude`?

Comment: Have you looked at any of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+software-center+black+screen) pages?

Comment: You could use Synaptic until it's fixed `$ sudo apt-get install synaptic` (It's the default application in debian for installing and uninstalling software).

Comment: `aptitude` giving same black screen

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's getting hung up on a particular operation that it's trying to perform, so the GUI is likely waiting for something else to complete that is either taking a long time to do so, or can't.

I'd try one of the 2 things to see if you can't isolate what's holding it up.

#### strace

You can try using `strace` to see what system call `software-center` is hanging on:

```
    $ strace software-center
```

#### open files

The other thing you can do is see what files `software-center` has opened.

```
    $ lsof -c software-cen
```

My suspicion would be that there is a lock file of some sort that is blocking `software-center` from proceeding.

#### What else?

I would go through the results on Google and see if you can't further characterize your issue and also compare the [multitude of other people that seem to be having the same issue with `software-center` freezing/hanging](https://www.google.com/search?q=software-center%20hangs&oq=software-center%20hangs&aqs=chrome.0.57j65l3j0l2.3751j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

Solved when deleted the cache of software-center:

```
$sudo rm -r .cache/software-center/
```

Now it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu it was solved by closing the window to force stop the running process, deleting the cache of software-center:

```
$ sudo rm -r .cache/software-center/
```